# E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_meta.lua:0: Invalid option (not found): 'data_dir'

Tags: neovim, init

I am using neovim config from custom directory and also want that it stores its data in custom directory. So i set this in my `~/.config/nvimcustom/init.lua` :

```lua
vim.opt.data_dir = '~/.local/share/nvimcustom/'
```

But on running `nvim -u ~/.config/nvimcustom/init.lua` , I am getting this error

```
Error detected while processing /home/venom/.config/nvimcustom/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: vim/_meta.lua:0: Invalid option (not found): 'data_dir'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'nvim_get_option_info'
vim/_meta.lua: in function '__index'
vim/_meta.lua: in function ''
vim/_meta.lua: in function '__newindex'
/home/venom/.config/nvimcustom/init.lua:2: in main chunk
```

I just want that my neovim config is present in custom directory and also all the plugins and otther data it stores due to this custom config is stored in a custom directory. How to do that.
I want to do it so that when I run normal nvim, I can have different configuration and whne I run nvim using -u flag, I can have different configuration

Comment: well, there just doesn't exists a `data_dir` option in neither Neovim nor Vim. I guess you want to configure `$XDG_DATA_HOME` depending on your use-case? See also here: https://neovim.io/doc/user/starting.html#xdg

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do on Windows. I have introduced a `nvimcustom.bat` script:

```
set XDG_CONFIG_HOME=%HOME%\nvimcustom
set XDG_DATA_HOME=%HOME%\nvimcustom
set XDG_STATE_HOME=%HOME%\nvimcustom

start Neovim\bin\nvim-qt.exe %*
```

On Linux it would be a `nvim.sh` script:

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$HOME/nvimcustom
XDG_DATA_HOME=$HOME/nvimcustom
XDG_STATE_HOME=$HOME/nvimcustom

nvim %*
```

The `init.lua` should then put into `~/nvimcustom/nvim`

Comment: So now when I start neovim normally without the -u flag, would it by default use my custom directory?

Comment: Indeed it will load `~/nvimcustom/nvim/init.lua` not exactly what you wish (`~/nvimcustom/init.lua`) but close :-). This is how I run different configuration of Neovim on my machine.

Comment: So now if i want to use .config/nvim, what do i type to load that, I am a little bit confused here

Comment: If you start `nvim` (without using the `nvim.sh` script) then the environment variable will not be defined and the `~/.conifg/nvim` will be used.